# How to insert < > in code?

Tags: discussion, new-users

When I am posting code using pre-code html tags, everything inside < > are lost, how to use html formatting correctly, so that I can see it ?

eg. if I have #include header.h, how can I use < > in header.h ?

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:** Backticks for in-line code escaping: `#include <header.h>`.

```
(`#include <header.h>`)
```

**Method 2:** Four spaces for code blocks:

```
#include <header.h>
```

(four spaces after two newlines, followed by #include <header.h>)

**Method 3:** Regular HTML escape codes: < >. (&lt; for < and &gt; for >)

Answer (score 1):

You can type

```
&lt; for < 
&gt; for >
```

---

Test below:

```
<Test>
```

---

Yea, it works.